# Apple’s podcast app will share statistics/analytics with creators and advertisers - how to opt-out (protect privacy)?

Tags: ios, itunes, appletv, podcasts, privacy

I use on AppleTV and iOS the podcast app weekly. In headlines there were sad news about privacy [Apple is going to let podcast creators — and advertisers — see what listeners actually like](https://www.recode.net/2017/6/10/15774936/apple-podcast-analytics-wwdc):

> A new version of Apple’s podcast app will provide basic analytics to
>   podcast creators, giving them the ability to see when podcast
>   listeners play individual episodes, and — crucially — what part of
>   individual episodes they listen to, which parts they skip over and
>   when they bail out of an episode.
>
> The reason all of that is important is that up until now, Apple has
>   provided almost no data at all about podcast listening behavior — just
>   the fact that someone has downloaded an individual episode.

How to opt-out of the data collection? Is there no other way than change Podcast client?

Comment: Let’s make a new thread for software recommendations. Tacking that on as a follow on question makes this too broad. Also, if you are asking about the beta feature, please edit that into the question. I’m not aware of a change in policy yet for the shipping versions of iOS or Apple TV but could be mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only affects iOS11 which is currently in beta (actually, only beta 2 has been released at this time).

We don't know if Apple will allow users to opt-out of this type of info-sharing with podcasters in the final shipping version of the OS.

The answer, for now, is no, you can't opt-out of this info sharing.  When the final version is shipped, this answer should be updated.

Comment: I should point out that even if Apple doesn't provide an opt-out option, the data will not identify individual users. Data will be presented in such a way that it's nothing more than raw numbers, percentages, timelines, etc. For example, there is no way to identify that a particular user always listens to a politics podcast every Monday morning and in doing so always skips the ads. It'll be more like, 13% of users who download your politics podcast listen to it on Monday mornings and so on and that 22% skip the ads and so on, and that 93% of users stop listening two mins before the end.